# High committed memory but small heap size

Tags: .net, debugging, memory, memory-leaks, windbg

One of my app is reported to be using 5 gigs memory, when i took the dump of the process and analyze in windbg, i can see that the total committed size is 5 gigs as was reported, but then the total managed heap size is only 1.6 gigs.

Question: what could cause the commit size to be so big when heap size is only a few gigs, I could see the MEM_COMMIT size was almost all used by PAGE_READWRITE sections, could it be possibly memory fragmentation?

State                 Size
MEM_COMMIT            5.653 Gb
MEM_RESERVE           2.597 Gb

GC Heap Size:    Size: 0x67cefd88 (1741618568) bytes.

Comment: Nobody can debug this for you with this little information.  Bitmaps are always a good way to swallow a lot of unmanaged memory.  Use a memory profiler.

Comment: I understand, but can you correct me-  if the committed memory size is bigger than the managed heap size, the extra memory is explained because of unmanaged memory or could it because of fragmentation? If the GC heap size is 1.6gigs, does it mean the rest of it is from unmanaged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the commit size not accounted in managed heap could come from fragmentation in unmanaged heaps. The command *!heap -s* will display them in windbg. 
You may also use [VMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533) to quickly rule out other kind of memory allocated data.